How to correctly use __shfl_up_sync for data transfer among only a few lanes
Suppose I need to shuffle some value from lane 29 to 30 and also from 30 to 31; what mask should I use?
Of course the mask should cover lane 30, 31 AND 29 (cuda guide says the source lane also needs to participate); but then the command must be called on lane 29 -- so do I need to continually expand the mask (finally to the full mask in this case) or do I just use 0xE0000000 and let the undefined result be returned for lane 29 (it doesn't need the result anyway)?

If you set the width parameter to 4, then you'd only need to add thread 28 to avoid all undefined behavior. Or you could use a __shfl_sync and make thread 29 read its own value (or of thread 31). Note that threads that don't appear in the mask should not execute the command. The PTX documentation makes it more clear that this results in undefined behavior.

The way a __shfl works is that every (partaking) thread presents its own value first and after that every threads takes a value from the pool. So, only the source is given, the dest, is always the asking thread.
You can model this using shared memory, I find it easier to picture it that way:
int shared_shfl(int old, int source) {
    //note shfl uses neither shared memory nor registers
    __shared__ int warpdata[32]; //one for every thread in the warp
    //step one: every thread presents its data
    warpdata[threadIdx.x] = old; 
    //step 2 synchronize
    __syncwarp(); 
    //step 3: get your data. 
    //Every thread can choose a different source, dest is always self.
    const auto new = warpdata[source]; 
    return new;
}
 

OK, let's list your requirements
29->29  //dest 29, offset = 0
29->30  //dest 30, offset = 1
30->31  //dest 31, offset = 1

It is perfectly valid for different threads to have a different offset.
The code will look like this:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>


__global__ void shfl_29() {
    auto dummydata = threadIdx.x % 32;
    const auto activemask = 0b111u << 29;
    const auto laneid = threadIdx.x % 32;
    const auto offset = int(laneid > 29); //29 = 0, else 1
    //the if statement must match the activemask, or your code will A: deadlock or B: not work.
    if (laneid >= 29) { 
        dummydata = __shfl_up_sync(activemask, dummydata, offset);
        printf("old: %i, new: %i\n", laneid, dummydata);
    }
    
}

int main() {
    shfl_29<<<1,256>>>();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();   
}


You can see it in action on Godbolt: https://cuda.godbolt.org/z/6E9bGbx1f
However, you need to be aware that using anything other than -1 as the activemask makes the shfl (and really any sync instruction) much slower.
A faster way to do this would be:
__global__ void shfl_29() {
    auto dummydata = threadIdx.x % 32;
    constexpr auto all = -1u;
    const auto laneid = threadIdx.x % 32;
    const auto offset = int(laneid > 29); //<=29? = 0, else 1
    dummydata = __shfl_up_sync(all, dummydata, offset);
    printf("old: %i, new: %i\n", laneid, dummydata);
}


If you time this, you'll see that the latter version runs about 10x faster, see: https://cuda.godbolt.org/z/c6q66P94h
